# Why are linear SVMs used with HoG feature descriptors?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, computer-vision

Ok, almost all applications I have seen that use HoG features use linear svm as classifier. Can someone explain for me why linear svm are chosen and why they give good performance?

Are linear svm chosen because it more simple and easier to train than svms that use polynomial or gaussian kernel and using these kernels is not giving significantly better performance?

Comment: I think you have a good answer here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73944/what-are-the-limitations-of-kernel-methods-and-when-to-use-kernel-methods/73945#73945. That depends on the size and characteristics of the data you refer to

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that HoG features already have a very high dimensionality. Increasing their dimensionality further by using a kernel simply does not improve accuracy.