# If the linear kernel function is the same as RBF with sigma = inf, then what is happening when the kernel scale is changed with a linear SVM?

Tags: svm, matlab, kernel-trick

From another answer here, I was linked to a paper:

[Linear kernel and non-linear kernel for support vector machine?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73032/linear-kernel-and-non-linear-kernel-for-support-vector-machine)

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.141.880&rep=rep1&type=pdf

So to clarify, I think that the linear cannot be better than rbf if you have the right parameters and that linear is just a worse version of rbf. Linear comes from rbf. 
Is this correct? Also, in Matlab I see sigma for kernel scale but not gamma. Are gamma and sigma the same?

Answer (score 1):

> I think that the linear cannot be better than rbf if you have the right parameters

Yes, that is shown in the linked paper.

> and that linear is just a worse version of rbf. Linear comes from rbf. Is this correct?

Linear kernel is the simple case of not using the kernel trick and you can get to it as a special case of the RBF kernel.

> Also, in Matlab I see sigma for kernel scale but not gamma. Are gamma and sigma the same?

The Gaussian (RBF) kernel should have 1 parameter (called *gamma* or *scale*). The linear kernel has no parameters.

Comment: Re: the last point, there are unfortunately many parameterizations of the Gaussian RBF kernel in relatively widespread use: the ones I know of are all of the form $\exp( - A \lVert x - y \rVert^2 )$ where $A$ can be $\gamma$, $\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2}$, $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$, $\frac{1}{\tau}$, among other variations.

Comment: Thanks! Can we say that there is 1 real-valued parameter?